# How to get a sub-table of rows that have a column which is equal to the MAX of the primary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

What I want to do is to get a sub-table of rows that have a column which is equal to the MAX of the primary table.

I illustrate with an example :

[image]

I want to get the ID that have, in priority :

- The lowest VALUE2.
- If several rows have the lowest VALUE2 (like in the example), they are differentated by the one who has the highest VALUE1
- If several rows have the highest VALUE1 and the lowest VALUE2, they are finally differentiated by the one who has the lowest ID

That is why I want to get subtables, because I have 3 filters of selection. I think this can be done by selecting step by step subtables but if you have a better idea (to improve performance) you can suggest it and I will be thankful :

Firstly, get the subtable of rows that have the lowest VALUE1, then get the sub-sub-table from the sub-table that have the highest VALUE2, then get the "sub-sub-subtable" that have lowest ID.

Anyone knows how to do this with the best performance possible ? (As a matter of fact, the rapidity of the response to this query is important in my application, as there is a lot of clients).

For the moment, I achieve to do this with this query, but it has apparently poor performance :

```
SELECT MIN(id) INTO id FROM (       SELECT id FROM (
                SELECT id, value1, value2 FROM table WHERE value2 IN (
                        SELECT MIN(value2) FROM table       )
                ) AS reqB WHERE value1 = (

        SELECT MIN(value1) FROM (
                        SELECT id, value1, value2 FROM table WHERE value2 IN (

                SELECT MIN(value2) FROM table           )
                    ) as reqC   ) ) as reqA;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select min(id), value1, value2 
from (
select *,
dense_rank() over(order by value2 asc, value1 desc) as rn
from tablename) t
where t.rn = 1
group by value1, value2;
```

You can use `dense_rank` function to get what you need.

Edit: Another solution on similar lines would be to use a `row_number` function, with all the ordering conditions in the `over` clause.

```
select id, value1, value2 
from (
select *,
row_number() over(order by value2 asc, value1 desc, id asc) as rn
from tablename) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: I am not sure why you would use `dense_rank`, then, get `min(id)`, why not just use `row_number()` in the first place and make the ordering `(order by value2 asc, value1 desc, id asc)` to ensure the first result. Saves a bit of grouping and aggregation at the end. Upvoted nonetheless, since it still answers the question and doubt there is a material difference from the extra grouping.

Comment: yes @GarethD..i thought there might be a caveat. Hence the solution above. I will edit it to include the `row_number` solution as well.

Comment: Thanks for both of you, it worked like a charm, so I can just upvote+check it ! I have an additional question : Do you think the row_number() solution is the best that can be done in terms of performance (response time) ?